# Display Month in Spanish using strftime?

Tags: c, strftime

I am trying to get the format a date from 2018-09-01 to September 1, 2018.
I have been using:

```
strftime(displayDate, sizeof(displayDate), "%B %d %Y", &date_obj);
```

It works perfectly, but, is there a way to format the Month to be in Spanish?

Comment: You must set the locale for Spanish first and then format the date string. See setlocale function.

Comment: Thank you. Will give it a try. If the locale is changed multiple times, can that cause issues with the OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `strftime` function formats dates based on the current locale.  So you'll need to set the locale for `LC_TIME` first:

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, "es_ES-UTF_8");
```

See [`setlocale`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=vs-2017) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. Will give it a try. If the locale is changed multiple times, can that cause issues with the OS?

Comment: @JaimeT Setting the locale with `setlocale` only affects the current process, and only the given locale category.